# How to acces to a specific row and a specific column in R without the column names?

Tags: r, dataframe

I begin with R Studio. I would like to access to the value located in the 5th row and 2nd column (without using the column names)

if I type

```
Result[5][2]
```

I receive this error message : Error in `[.data.frame`(Result[5], 2) : undefined columns selected

but if I type

```
Result$X1[5]
```

I receive : [1] 10

It seems that My table (2 dimensions) is considered as a "list". Is it the problem? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try `Result[5, 2]`

Comment: easy !!! thanks and sorry to disturb xp